# Keeping element centred with slider (while following)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Right so I had a question to help with the first bit of this and that was just getting a `div` to follow the slider knob. After messing around with it for a while we came up with the solution. Now I have a `div` following the slider knob I need it centred on it at all times.

So to keep this an simple as possible here is a image of what I am trying to fix.

[image]

In the image above you can see the slider and the `div` that is following the slider knob. Under that I have places `|` so you can see that its not fully centred with slider knob. I need this to be centred under the slider knob at all times (in the image it should be under/in the middle of the gray bit). It tends to start to mess up when going 40% and below as well as 60% and above.

**What I have tried:**

I can't think of an easy way to fix this (hence this post) but I did try a little cheat by doing the following:

```
if (pct >= 80) {
    // Position the follow div and arrow
    $('#follow').css('left', (o.value * 0.98) + '%');
} else if (pct >= 70) {
    $('#follow').css('left', (o.value * 0.99) + '%');
} else if (pct <= 50 & pct >= 40) {
    $('#follow').css('left', (o.value * 1.02) + '%');
} else if (pct <= 40 & pct >= 30) {
    $('#follow').css('left', (o.value * 1.04) + '%');
} else if (pct <= 30 & pct >= 20) {
    $('#follow').css('left', (o.value * 1.08) + '%');
}
```

Now what this does it trys to keep the `div` on track with the slider by changing the `%` as it moves along. This does work (kinda) but leads to the `div` not being smooth and it goes all jumpy due to the calculation corrections.

**Here is an example of what I have so far:**

### HTML:

```
<div class="slider-container">
    <div id="follow-container">
        <div id="follow">I am following the slider!
            <br />
            <div id="percentage"></div>
            <br />|</div>
    </div>
    <div id="testslider"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
#testslider {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: -40px;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center;
}
.slider-container {
    padding: 55px;
}
#follow-container {
    position: relative;
    left: -65px;
    bottom: 2px;
}
#follow {
    position: absolute;
    width: 193px;
    height:40px;
    margin-left: -77px;
    /* half width */
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

### JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('#testslider').sGlide({
    height: 16,
    startAt: 70,
    colorStart: '#C6F1F8',
    colorEnd: '#C6F1F8',
    drag: function (o) {
        var pct = Math.round((o.value));
        $('#percentage').html(pct);

        // Position the follow div and arrow
        $('#follow').css('left', o.value + '%');

    },
    onButton: function (o) {
        var pct = Math.round(o.value) + '%';
        $('#percentage').html(pct);
    }
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/zRA9F/)

Any help here would be great and as people before have said "so what is your question".

**Overall question:**  How can I keep the following `div` aligned with the slider knob?

Comment: learning to separate question from the theory as compare to the last time i see...nice!! :)

Comment: Yup, that last bit was purely for you! I have seen stuck on this for a little while now and thought its about time I made a question for it. This is very annoying for such a small thing.

Comment: Almost near - http://jsfiddle.net/zRA9F/5/

Comment: @Mr.Alien that's pretty close. So close! yet so far away (better then anything I have come up with, and im still at it)

Comment: @Ruddy Let me tell you the big thing, you are using `%` so even if you resize your window, the calculations will go wrong, see to it that you have fixed `width` container

Comment: @Mr.Alien The screen size will always be the same so I don't need to worry about that. But yeah a fixed width container can always go around it.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Also all the `left: 40px;` etc are the position I have it on the page I need it like that.

Comment: @Ruddy Yea I got rid of them, but you can get an idea of how I did, tweak around a bit or give me some more time :) and also, when you are debugging this, make the width's fix, lil resize in the window, and you will go wrong with the calculations

Comment: @Mr.Alien As I said Im still working on it doing many different things to try and get it working. I look forward to see what you also come up with.

Comment: @Ruddy sure :) till than keep tweaking

Comment: @Mr.Alien I think I just found a way to do it..... It was as simple as setting a width to the `follow-container`. Only just testing now but at first look it seems to have fixed it.

Comment: @Ruddy Do answer your own question if it fixes ...

Comment: @Mr.Alien Very odd, if I do it in a fiddle it doesn't completely fix it. Yet on my real version it does.

Comment: @Ruddy because you haven't resetted the css in your jsfiddle :)

Comment: @Ruddy : great...i wish i could upvote u guys....post your solution as an answer...sure i will then!! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor I put an answer up, I doubt anyone else will have this problem but you never know. Such a simple solution in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all this it turns out to solve my problem I needed to give `#follow-container` a width.

Giving this the correct with of the slider allowed the child `div` to align correctly with the slider knob.

**Example:**

```
#follow-container {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 2px;
    width: 760px;
    left: -100px;
}
```

This seems to have fixed my problem on my real project, thanks for all the help [**NoobEditor**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3154233/noobeditor) and [**Mr.Alien**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1542290/mr-alien).

Comment: @NoobEditor Have to wait 2 days to be able to do that, but I will when it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

Only way i can see it work is to wrap the `|` inside  `span` class!!

[**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zRA9F/3/)

**HTML**

```
<span class="vline"><br />|</span>
```

**CSS**

```
#follow > span.vline {
    position: relative;
    left:4%;
}
```

**EDIT**

as per the comments discussion, this is probably your treasure!!

[**solution**](http://jsfiddle.net/zRA9F/4/)  (*based on you question fiddle, not my 1st attempted fiddle*)

**css**

```
 #follow-container {
        position: fixed; /*changed*/
        left:50%; /* change as per your need, left:60%; would make it 
 center to the full 100% width*/
        margin-left:-96px; /*half of divs width*/
    }
```

Comment: I need the whole `div` aligned not just `|` that's only there to show you that the `div` isn't aligned otherwise its not very obvious. Sorry if I didn't make that clear. Also even that doesn't work.

Comment: the div having `I am following the slider!` follows the slider...you want *that* to be fixed in the center....????or may be i need to join some english class now!! :|

Comment: Not just the text, the whole `div`. So the middle of the `div` will be following the slider knob (little gray bit).

Comment: Nope, you don't seem to understand me lol. The slider knob (little gray bit) will be followed by the `div` (with the text in it) That `div` needs to be centered on that slider knob at all times even when its moving. At the moment the `div` goes very slightly off center when dragging the slider knob.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45105/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-ruddy)